# <iframe> makes browser running forever

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Here is my document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>iframe test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe id="frm"></iframe>
    <script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
      let content = "<h1>Hello world</h1>";
      document.getElementById("frm").contentDocument.write(content);
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I open it on Firefox or Chrome, it works but the browser runs indefinitely. How can I fix this problem?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const content = "<h1>Hello world</h1>";
const frm = document.getElementById("frm");
//for cross-browser compatibility
const frmCnt = frm.contentWindow || frm.contentDocument.document || frm.contentDocument;
//needed to write inside the already generated <html></html> tags of the iframe
const frmDoc = frmCnt.document;
frmDoc.open();
frmDoc.write(content);
frmDoc.close();
```